# SPO - How to populate select field with options JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jsom, choice-field

I want to populate all choices from SP(ChoiceField) into html select field...

**This is my code:**

```
function pageLoad() {
   var holidayList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Holidays");
   var protocolChoices = clientContext.castTo(holidayList.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle("LirexHolidayProtocol"), SP.FieldChoice);
   var protocolOtherChoices = clientContext.castTo(holidayList.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle("LirexHolidayProtocolOther"), SP.FieldChoice);

   clientContext.load(protocolChoices);
   clientContext.load(protocolOtherChoices);
   clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, successHandler), Function.createDelegate(this, errorHandler));

 //Fill DDls with protocols
   var choices = protocolChoices.get_choices();
   //alert("Choices: (" + choices.length + ") - " + choices.join(", "));

   var options = $("#noFunnyHoliday");
   $.each(choices, function () {
        options.append($("<option />").val(ChoiceNum).text(ChoiceValue));
   });
 }
```

> **1)** What is the best way to fill select element with options(choices)...(*Resolved*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope choices is already filled with text and Value.

```
$.each(choices , function(val, text) {
    $('#noFunnyHoliday').append( new Option(text,val) );
});
```

---

Thanks

Comment: I'll try, moment :)